# Having an issue with HTML forms on a CSS Parallax

Tags: html, css, forms

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3pnytb7e/2/) of the page. All the way at the bottom is the Form. I can't figure out why I can't fill it out. I thought it was a `z-index` issue but no such luck.

```
<form action="MAILTO:******" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="text" name="name" value="First, Last"><br>
Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="mail" value="Email"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" value="Comments" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

It really is just a simple HTML form.

Answer (score 2):

`.slide::before` has `position:absolute;` and it covers the whole `.slide` so you can add `position:relative` and `z-index` to `form` to put form on top of `.slide::before`.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/3pnytb7e/3/)

Comment: Thanks @alireza-safian !

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3pnytb7e/4/)

Add this to your CSS

```
#slide4 form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

**OR**

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.slide::before`

```
.slide::before {
    content: "";
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with fill out since I could fill it out, but if you mean, when you click on the input, you want the value away, you can use:
`placeholder` instead of `value`.

```
<input type="text" name="mail" value="Email">
```

To

```
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Email">
```